# How to access to element of a class by string name in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I get name of font awesome from api that I want to access element of font_awesome_flutter package but I know it in C# but I do not know in flutter:
received from server:

```
{
  "fontawesomeName":"breadSlice"
}
```

in font_awesome package I can access its element by below

```
 IconButton(
            icon: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.breadSlice),
             onPressed: () { print("Pressed"); }
           )
```

But How do I access element of object with string name in flutter?

Comment: why do you want to access it using string? is not the current syntax enough for your use case?

Comment: and a simple switch case statement can convert those strings into class members if you really want to access class members using string id.

Comment: I only get name from api without id

Comment: yes, you can compare the string name using if-else statement or switch statement or crate a map of elements.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in Flutter because reflection is disabled. The only way is to create a mapping. For example:

```
const Map<String, IconData> map = {
  "breadSlice": FontAwesomeIcons.breadSlice,
};

IconData getIcon(String iconName) {
  return map[iconName];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting elements by their name in a string is called "reflection". I vaguely remember that regular Dart had it but Flutter's Dart did not.

However, this package may be helpful: https://pub.dev/packages/reflectable